# How to extend mpz_class in c++

Tags: c++, class, gmp

I want to create my own class that is similar to `mpz_class` except has a few extra methods.  I have however heard it is not a good idea to extend `std` classes.  Does this advice apply here or can I safely do:

```
class MyBigInt : public mpz_class {
public:
    long double specialMethod() {
        //do something that returns a long double
    }
}
```

The reason I am interested in extending is I still want the ability to do

```
mpz_class a,b,c;
a=5;
b=6;
c=a+b;
```

so if extending is a bad idea I need to some how figure out how to make the above work with my own class.

Comment: What makes you think extending a GMP class is a bad idea?

Comment: `mpz_class` is not a `std` class

Comment: `mpz_class` is not standard.  Also, please add the appropriate tags, since C++ is not sufficient.

Comment: I know ```mpz_class``` is not a ```std``` class which is why I specifically asked if the advice still applied.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have no idea if it is a good idea or bad.  I can do it but that doesn't mean there are some unforeseen side effects.  I am very new to c++ and when I saw advice against doing for std i wanted to check if that applies to other libraries.

Comment: `boost::multiprecision` has nice C++ wrappers for gmp, if you can use it.

Comment: It is going to be hard to make something like that work, sorry. For a quick prototype, you could just edit gmpxx.h and add your function.